# handlebars + json to show output partially (split json data? )

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/5kkja1ua/

```
<ul id="results"></ul>

<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="item_tmpl">
    {{#json}}
    <p>     {{index}}: {{title}} </p>
    {{/json}}

    <button>next</button>
</script>

var dataObject = {
  json:[
  {
    "index": 0,
    "title": "IMAGEFLOW"
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "title": "ENERSOL"
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "title": "BUNGA"
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "title": "BITENDREX"
  },
  {
    "index": 4,
    "title": "MAROPTIC"
  },
  {
    "index": 5,
    "title": "AEORA"
  },
  {
    "index": 6,
    "title": "PYRAMIA"
  },
  {
    "index": 7,
    "title": "ANIXANG"
  },
  {
    "index": 8,
    "title": "SNORUS"
  }
]
}; 

var tpl_source = $("#item_tmpl").html();
var h = Handlebars.compile(tpl_source);
var content = h(dataObject);

// output
var results = document.getElementById("results");
results.innerHTML = content;
```

One method I can do it easily is to get 3 items wrapped (by using `slice()`) in a div and then hide and show. However, this method needs to load the whole lot first.

I'd like to know if possible to have the output to show every 3 items as a group? if possible to split the json data?

```
0: IMAGEFLOW

1: ENERSOL

2: BUNGA
```

then click next to show another 3 items and so on. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about to create handlebars helper to use each with suport from/to parameters, like

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_from_to', function(ary, from, max, options) {

    from || (from = 0);
    var result = [ ];

    for(var i = from; i < from + max && i < ary.length; ++i)
        result.push(options.fn(ary[i]));

    return result.join('');
});
```

After that your template will looks like

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="item_tmpl">
    {{#each_from_to json startFrom rowsOnPage}}
    <p>     {{index}}: {{title}} </p>
    {{/each_from_to}}
</script>
```

Check this fiddle. Does it solve your problem?
http://jsfiddle.net/5kkja1ua/1/

Comment: Many thanks @VadimB, never used Helper before How do I reverse?  do I need to create a new helper?

Comment: Or just include one more boolean parameter into current helper and change direction based on it `#each_from_to json startFrom rowsOnPage false`.  So your helper declaration will look like `Handlebars.registerHelper('each_from_to', function(ary, from, max, forward, options) { if(forward === undefined) { forward = true; }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ticked it. one last question, I never used helper so just want to know how to debug or "know" if the "FIRST" / "Last" bit of json data, so I can hide and show "Next" button. Thanks

Comment: Actually you have your array reference inside your helper. So you can easy compare with its length do detect that you are at the end. About hiding button - I think easiest way to hide - its add handlebars `if` statement and compare if your `startFrom + rowsOnPage < json.length`. Hide prev on first page - also `if` statement with `startFrom == 0`.

Comment: much appreciated your help. If json data is more than 200 items,  from optimization aspect, I think this method is better (I could be wrong) than wrap every 3 items and then show and hide.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Here you have less DOM render operations, so performance should be much better.

Comment: can this helper or helper support like pagination? page 1 to show 1 -3 items, page 2 to show 4-6 and so on? if possible to gimme some hints? Thanks a lot

Comment: But why you need this inside helpet? It only iterator. Move it outside - you have `{{startFrom}}` your first value, {{startFrom + rowsOnPage}} - your last.